# Аргументы gcc для отладки шаблонов. (C++)

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, компиляция, gcc

С какими аргументами командной строки нужно запускать GCC чтобы посмотреть в какие именно функции (или классы) и в какое место программы инстанцировался шаблон.

Comment: как-то делал такое через `libclang`, но это, по сути, был свой кастомный инструмент

Comment: Вот обсуждение на английском SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448094/can-we-see-the-template-instantiated-code-by-c-compiler

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Я обычно использую вот этот инструмент - https://cppinsights.io/

Он позволяет развернуть все шаблоны и посмотреть. Там несть возможность выбирать стандарт и некоторые особенности "разворачивания".

Следует заметить, что если в коде нет использования шаблона, а только сам код шаблона, то он не будет развернут и ничего не будет "видно".

Comment: А где там возможность "развернуть все шаблоны"? На вид как обычный онлайн компилятор.

Comment: треугольник нажимали?

Comment: https://cppinsights.io/ - отличный инструмент. То, что нужно. Благодарю.